# How reload data with new fetch?

Tags: swift, swift2

When I loaded my view and called `didload`, I executed `fetch` from Core Data. For example, I have 10 records in row, now when I add new row I have from 1 to 11 rows. But after I add a new row, I want to reload table view with only last 10 rows again. How can I call `tableView.reloadData()` with the same fetch execute like on `didload`?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: MInstance.getMessagesList(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        do { try fetchedResultsController?.performFetch() } catch _ {}

        // Refresh table view
        chatTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement following delegate methods of `NSFetchedResultsController`

```
controllerWillChangeContent(_:)
controller(_:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:)
controller(_:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:)
controllerDidChangeContent(_:)
```

Reference https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008228-CH1-SW13

Answer (score 0):

In your `tableView:numberOfRows` in section, you can return the minimum of 10 and the amount of items that the FRC has found.  Then, your tableView refresh should be limited to 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { 

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

         chatTableView.reloadData()

        }

}
```

then edit

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 10

}
```